# Overlay 2 images with css only

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images that I will like to overlay on top of each other like photoshop clipping mask effect.

This is what I want to achieve [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Zd8.jpg)
I know using -webkit-background-clip: text I can achieve the recovery since it's text. But what I want to achieve is using 2 images.

Comment: use `position` property it might help u

Answer (score 0):

check output in [Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gesaxiy/edit?html)

use `Position:relative` and then adjust using `top`, `bottom`,`left`,`right` according to situation

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Picture</title>
  <style>
    .a {
      position: relative;
      left: 180px;
      top: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JljSPeY.jpg" class="a" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/abF4DbL.jpg" class="b" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is what i am looking for as the text recovery has no background-color.

Comment: I mean this is not what I am looking for.